# Regular Expression for no repeat character

Tags: c#, regex

I have the below regular expression.

```
^((?=.{10,32}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]))
```

The regular expression has the following functionality:

1. Passwords will contain at least (1) upper case letter
2. Passwords will contain at least (1) lower case letter
3. Length of password to be between 10 to 32

I want to add one more validation. I do not want any continuous repeating character.

Can you please help me?

Comment: You don't want to have characters repeated back to back i.e `AAA` or anywhere in the string i.e `ABCDA` ?

Comment: I do not want charcter repeat back to back. If repeated anywhere then its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Negative Lookahead to do this.

```
^(?=.{10,32}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*(.)\1).+$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yM9jQ2/1)

Answer (score 1):

This would match any pair of identical characters:

```
"(.)\1"
```

Here little program.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "12223";
        string b = "P12345";


        bool z = Regex.IsMatch(a,@"(.)\1");
        bool x = Regex.IsMatch(b,@"(.)\1");

    }
```